# Same script giving different results for Google Apps account domainUser

Tags: google-apps-script

I am a super administrator for two Google Apps for Education Accounts and I'm getting different results for the same script in both domains.  Here is the script :

```
function listUsers(s) {     
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  sheet.getDataRange().clear()
  var users = UserManager.getAllUsers();
  var r = new Array();
  var f = new Array();
  var Uconnect = '';

  for( var i = 0 ; i < users.length ; i++ ){
    var Umail = users[i].getEmail(); 
    var UnomF = users[i].getFamilyName()
    var UnomP = users[i].getGivenName()

    if(users[i].getAgreedToTerms()){Uconnect = 'yes'}else{Uconnect = 'never'}

    r.push([UnomF,UnomP,Umail,Uconnect]);
    if(i%2==0){
      f.push(['#eeeeff','#eeeeff','#eeeeff','#eeeeff']);
    }else{
      f.push(['#ffffff','#ffffff','#ffffff','#ffffff']);
    }
  }   
  r.sort(function(x,y){
    var xp = x[0].toLowerCase();
    var yp = y[0].toLowerCase();
    Logger.log(xp+'   '+yp)
    return xp == yp ? 0 : xp < yp ? -1 : 1;//  sort on name ascending
  }
        )
  var header = ['Nom de famille','Prénom','Email','Déjà Connecté?']
  sheet.getRange(1,1,1,r[0].length).setValues([header]).setFontWeight('bold')
  .setBackground('silver').setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true);
  sheet.getRange(2,1,r.length,r[0].length).setValues(r);
  sheet.getRange(2,1,f.length,f[0].length).setBackgroundColors(f);
  sheet.getDataRange().setVerticalAlignment('middle').setFontSize(11);
}
```

The script is very simple : it gets all the domain users and shows a list in a spreadsheet with some formatting. It is also supposed to show wether users have initialize their accounts using the [getAgreedToTerms()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/domain/domain-user#getAgreedToTerms%28%29) method from the domainUser class.

On one of the domains I get real results (identical to what I can see in the Google Apps admin control panel) but in the second one `getAgreedToTerms()` returns always `true`, even for newly created users.(From what I can see the domain settings are the same.)

Is there something I am missing somewhere ? Is there another way to check wether a user has connected himself with his account ?

I know this is not really a programming question but I also know that many of us have Google Apps accounts and users to administrate :-) so I decided it's worth trying.

Comment: Hey ! Thanks... I was kind of waiting for it tonight :-)  you did it!!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did the domains get created at similar time? There have been quite a number of back end upgrade as google transitioned from its old GApps infrastructure, we've seen settings that are not propagated on occasion.

I guess the best way forward is to use the Admin SDK and see wether your results are consistent with what you are getting through the Apps Script wrapper. Its pretty cool, you can authenticate and get the results within the page itself.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, the 'working'  domain was created in 2009, the other in April this year...do you think it could be the cause of this? The Admin SDK is probably a good idea although I've no experience at all with that but this could be a good motivation to start digging it :-)

Comment: Yes 2009 is quite a long time back, before the new infrastructure indeed, but I would have guess that was the domain not working.  You should be able to create a ticket for that with support, they sometimes just need to do some work in the backend to make things right, especially if the result the same with the Admin SDK?  Years ago we liked to called them the gremlins in the data center, as every change took very long to propagate trough the set of user.